# React resetting and preserving state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> By default, React preserves state of a component while it stays at the
> same position. Usually, this is exactly what you want, so it makes
> sense as the default behavior.

Examples are taken from the new [React docs](https://react.dev/learn/preserving-and-resetting-state#resetting-state-at-the-same-position).

`Example 1 - the same position`, [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/8jbk5?file=/App.js&from-sandpack=true),  (relevant code) :

```
  return (
    <div>
      {isPlayerA ? (
        <Counter person="Taylor" />
      ) : (
        <Counter person="Sarah" />
      )}
      <button onClick={() => {
        setIsPlayerA(!isPlayerA);
      }}>
        Next player!
      </button>
    </div>
  );
```

`Example 2 - different position`, [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/is7iw?file=/App.js&from-sandpack=true), (relevant code):

```
  return (
    <div>
      {isPlayerA &&
        <Counter person="Taylor" />
      }
      {!isPlayerA &&
        <Counter person="Sarah" />
      }
      <button onClick={() => {
        setIsPlayerA(!isPlayerA);
      }}>
        Next player!
      </button>
    </div>
  );
```

I'm confused why the position in `Example 2` is considered different? In both cases only one `Counter`  component is rendered. What am I missing?

Comment: My guess is the first example is CounterA/CounterB and a button, the second example is false/CounterA, false/CounterB and a button. react will not render the false value. So the children array for the second example might look like [false, Counter, button] or [Counter, false, button]

Comment: @JacobSmit as far as I know, if first for example is false it's just ignored

Comment: People have already beaten me to it, the only thing I will add is that it's possible to make react treat example 1 the same way it treats example 2. React uses keys to identify each component between rerenders, when you don't supply one it attempts to automatically figure out what the key should be (this is where the child position comes in, change in position means a change in the automatic key). Change example 1 
 ternary statement too: `isPlayerA ? <Counter key="Taylor" person="Taylor" /> : <Counter key="Sarah" person="Sarah" />` will make it drop the state when swapping the condition

Comment: @JacobSmit - The doc says "Remember that it’s the position in the UI tree—not in the JSX markup—that matters to React! " So, your suggesting the false is present in the UI tree and not rendered?

Comment: That is what his examples appear to suggest to me. I'm not keen enough to go through https://github.com/facebook/react and find the code that handles this, but if someone else is I'd be interested in seeing it.

Comment: @HimanshuSingh Your code is wrong. your `useEffect()` doesn't have dependency.

Comment: Ya right, just added it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very interesting :)

example 1 could be replaced like this.

```
  return (
    <div>
      <Counter person={isPlayerA ? "Taylor" : "Sarah"} />
      {/* isPlayerA ? (
        <Counter person="Taylor" />
      ) : (
        <Counter person="Sarah" />
      ) */}
      <button onClick={() => {
        setIsPlayerA(!isPlayerA);
      }}>
        Next player!
      </button>
    </div>
  );
```

`<Counter />` won't be unmounted because only the `person` prop has changed.

but example 2 is different.

```
  return (
    <div>
      {isPlayerA &&
        <Counter person="Taylor" />
      }
      {!isPlayerA &&
        <Counter person="Sarah" />
      }
      <button onClick={() => {
        setIsPlayerA(!isPlayerA);
      }}>
        Next player!
      </button>
    </div>
  );
```

There are 2 `<Counter />` and they are toggled mounted/unmounted

Comment: Wow, I got it now. Thanks!

Comment: @HimanshuSingh I don't agree because your code has wrong. you missed dependency on `useEffect()`

Answer (score 3):

The difference might become more obvious if you don't use the JSX syntax, but normal JavaScript instead.

The first codeblock would look like this:

```js
return (
  React.createElement("div", {},
    isPlayerA ? (
      React.createElement(Counter, { person: "Taylor" })
    ) : (
      React.createElement(Counter, { person: "Sarah" })
    ),
    React.createElement("button",
      { onClick: () => { setIsPlayerA(!isPlayerA); } },
      "Next player!"
    )
  )
);
```

Now pay close attention to the argument positions of the most outer `createElement()` call. If we assume `isPlayerA` is `true` then we get the following output:

```js
return (
  React.createElement("div", {},
    React.createElement(Counter, { person: "Taylor" }),
    React.createElement("button",
      { onClick: () => { setIsPlayerA(!isPlayerA); } },
      "Next player!"
    )
  )
);
```

If `isPlayerA` is `false` we get:

```js
return (
  React.createElement("div", {},
    React.createElement(Counter, { person: "Sarah" }),
    React.createElement("button",
      { onClick: () => { setIsPlayerA(!isPlayerA); } },
      "Next player!"
    )
  )
);
```

Notice that both counters are the 3rd argument of `createElement()`. So React will assume it is the same component called with different props.

The second codeblock could be written like so:

```js
return (
  React.createElement("div", {},
    isPlayerA && React.createElement(Counter, { person: "Taylor" }),
    !isPlayerA && React.createElement(Counter, { person: "Sarah" }),
    React.createElement("button",
      { onClick: () => { setIsPlayerA(!isPlayerA); } },
      "Next player!"
    )
  )
);
```

Now assuming that `isPlayerA` is `true`, you would the following output:

```js
return (
  React.createElement("div", {},
    React.createElement(Counter, { person: "Taylor" }),
    false,
    React.createElement("button",
      { onClick: () => { setIsPlayerA(!isPlayerA); } },
      "Next player!"
    )
  )
);
```

And if `isPlayerA` is `false` the output will be:

```js
return (
  React.createElement("div", {},
    false,
    React.createElement(Counter, { person: "Sarah" }),
    React.createElement("button",
      { onClick: () => { setIsPlayerA(!isPlayerA); } },
      "Next player!"
    )
  )
);
```

Again, look closely at the outer `createElement()` arguments. You see that the `Counter` component jumps between the 3rd and 4th argument position, depending on the value of `isPlayerA`.

Because it jumps to another argument position React assumes that it's a different Component, therefore unmounting the previous component and mounting a new one.

Answer (score 1):

This has entirely to do with the node position within the tree hierarchy: if the same component or node type is not rendered at exactly the same position in the tree, React will consider it to be different. Other answers already cover this, so I'll focus on another important part:

In the reconciliation section of the React docs, the nature of this dilemma is discussed, and a solution is presented: the `key` attribute.

> In order to solve this issue, React supports a `key` attribute. When children have keys, React uses the key to match children in the original tree with children in the subsequent tree.

I won't copy and paste the entire documentation here, but you can read it at https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#keys

Here is an example which demonstrates using a common key to help React maintain state across renders when the element position changes **among its siblings**:

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
}

button {
  display: block;
  margin: 0.5rem 0;
}

code {
  background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 50%, 0.15);
  padding: 0.2em;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div><script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.16.4/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel" data-type="module" data-presets="react">

const {useState} = React;

function Counter ({person}) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>{person}</div>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(c => c + 1)}>Count: {count}</button>
    </div>
  );
}

function SameNodePosition () {
  const [isFirstPlayer, setIsFirstPlayer] = useState(true);
  const togglePlayer = () => setIsFirstPlayer(bool => !bool);
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Same node position</h2>
      {
        isFirstPlayer ? <Counter person="Taylor" /> : <Counter person="Sarah" />
      }
      {/* Can also be written like this:
        <Counter person={isFirstPlayer ? 'Taylor' : 'Sarah'} />
      */}
      <button onClick={togglePlayer}>Toggle player</button>
    </div>
  );
}

function DifferentNodePosition () {
  const [isFirstPlayer, setIsFirstPlayer] = useState(true);
  const togglePlayer = () => setIsFirstPlayer(bool => !bool);
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Different node position</h2>
      { isFirstPlayer && <Counter person="Taylor" /> }
      { !isFirstPlayer && <Counter person="Sarah" /> }
      <button onClick={togglePlayer}>Toggle player</button>
    </div>
  );
}

function DifferentSiblingNodePositionWithSameKey () {
  const [isFirstPlayer, setIsFirstPlayer] = useState(true);
  const togglePlayer = () => setIsFirstPlayer(bool => !bool);
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Different sibling node position with same <code>key</code></h2>
      { isFirstPlayer && <Counter key="playerCounter" person="Taylor" /> }
      { !isFirstPlayer && <Counter key="playerCounter" person="Sarah" /> }
      <button onClick={togglePlayer}>Toggle player</button>
    </div>
  );
}

function DifferentNonSiblingNodePositionWithSameKey () {
  const [isFirstPlayer, setIsFirstPlayer] = useState(true);
  const togglePlayer = () => setIsFirstPlayer(bool => !bool);
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Different non-sibling node position with same <code>key</code></h2>
      { isFirstPlayer && <Counter key="playerCounter" person="Taylor" /> }
      <div>
        { !isFirstPlayer && <Counter key="playerCounter" person="Sarah" /> }
      </div>
      <button onClick={togglePlayer}>Toggle player</button>
    </div>
  );
}

function Example () {
  return (
    <div>
      <SameNodePosition />
      <DifferentNodePosition />
      <DifferentSiblingNodePositionWithSameKey />
      <DifferentNonSiblingNodePositionWithSameKey />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, both Counter will preserve the same state because the are rendered one at a time in the same exact position in DOM Tree. React thinks they are the same because the position. Latter by definition, Counter Taylor and Sarah are rendered at different location in DOM Tree. Therefore react thinks they are different and give them their own state.

Another option which produce same result as the second example is option 2 where even though they are switched in the same position, they have different keys therefore considered different.

Remember, react only sees component in DOM Tree and preserve their states only if they are rendered.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, the final result is same but how they are implemented are different.

I am considering the examples right from the doc.

#### Example 1

```
{isPlayerA ? (
    <Counter person="Taylor" />
) : (
    <Counter person="Sarah" />
)}
```

In `Taylor` & `Sarah`, **`<Counter/>`** **rendering** of both is **interrelated** and here the relation is created by the ternary operator. I any case, only one will be shown as we do in `else if` or `if else` conditions.

**For example:**

```
{isPlayerA ? (
   <Counter person="Taylor" />
) : isPlayerB ? (
   <Counter person="Sarah" />
) : isPlayerC ? (
   <Counter person="Corner" />
) : (<Counter person="Jason" /> 
)}
```

There are interrealted as

> whenever react finds any of the condition to be true, it will skip the rest checks. Like if it finds `isPlayerB`, then it will skip all the `isPlayerC` checks present in `else` section of playerB.

as in the image, the balance is the `else if` conditions.
[image]

---

#### Example 2

```
{isPlayerA &&
  <Counter person="Taylor" />
}
{!isPlayerA &&
  <Counter person="Sarah" />
}
```

In this case, the rendering is not interrelated, it is just that the variable deciding the rendering is same and thus you can say both are interrelated.

React will check all such conditions, no matter what to do final rendering. Even if it is like this

**For example:**

```
{isPlayerA &&
  <Counter person="Taylor" />
}
{!isPlayerA &&
  <Counter person="Sarah" />
}
{isPlayerB &&
  <Counter person="Jason" />
}
{!isPlayerB &&
  <Counter person="Tyler" />
}
```

> Here, react will check all the conditions, from 1 to 4, and the one who matches will be shown. If `playerA` === `true`, it will still check for `!playerA` and similarly for `playerB` as well.

As in the image, React is just striking out the elements that are not matching the conditions, there is not any kind of relation in between them.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because React treats the definition of both Counter as different elements through shallow equality. Remember in JS, `{} === {}` will equal false.

On the render where we changed players, it sees that the counter component of the previous render to be of a different instantiation through that if switch.

To preserve the position, you may add a key (should be the same value) on both components if you want the desired effect of preserving the state, or you know, just toggle the person props.

Answer (score 0):

To grasp the distinction, it's important to recognize that the persistence of a component's state hinges on whether the component is **returned** in the exact same location (the final visual output on the screen isn't the determining factor).

When using the ternary operator, the outcome is one of the components being **returned** (ensuring state preservation as long as the component is positioned in the same location).

```
{isPlayerA ? (
 <Counter person="Taylor" />
  ) : (
    <Counter person="Sarah" />
  )}
```

returns one of the components.

On the other hand, using the `&&` operator results in the return of the first falsy value encountered. E.g.: if isPlayerA is false, the returned result is false.

```
{isPlayerA &&
  <Counter person="Taylor" />
}
```

returns false.

```
{!isPlayerA &&
        <Counter person="Sarah" />
      }
```

returns the component.

In this scenario, the distinction emerges where the component isn't returned in its original location. Instead, the `false` value takes its place.

It's important to note that even though this `false` value is not painted on the screen, it does affect the state preservation.