# React: Rendering a component in different positions. What's the definiton of different position in a render tree for reconciliation?

Tags: reactjs, reconciliation

Currently I'm reading the [react beta official document](https://beta.reactjs.org/).

When I read [this part](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/preserving-and-resetting-state#option-1-rendering-a-component-in-different-positions), I'm very confused about the definition of rendering a component in different positions.

```
// Code from official document
export default function Scoreboard() {
  const [isPlayerA, setIsPlayerA] = useState(true);
  return (
    <div>
      // If we use this pattern, the Counter state will not be preserved
      {isPlayerA &&
        <Counter person="Taylor" />
      }
      {!isPlayerA &&
        <Counter person="Sarah" />
      }

      // If we use this pattern, the Counter state will be preserved
      {/*isPlayerA ? <Counter person="Taylor" /> : <Counter person="Sarah" />*/} 

      <button onClick={() => {
        setIsPlayerA(!isPlayerA);
      }}>
        Next player!
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

function Counter({ person }) {
...
}
```

In the above example, the state in the Counter will be reset because the document said that they will be mount in different positions. However, I'm confused that why they're in different positions?
and why another conditional rendering pattern(see the comment above) can preserve state? What's the difference between them?

I've also experimented something, but get confused even more.

```
export default function Scoreboard() {
  const [isPlayerA, setIsPlayerA] = useState(true);
  return (
    <div>
        {isPlayerA && <div>Up</div>}
        {isPlayerA ? <Counter  person="Taylor" /> : <Counter  person="Sarah" />} 
        {!isPlayerA && <div>Down</div>}

      <button onClick={() => {
        setIsPlayerA(!isPlayerA);
      }}>
        Next player!
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In the above experiment, the Counter state is preserved also. However, Counter component will be in different position when the `isPlayer` state changed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React resetting and preserving state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70253988/react-resetting-and-preserving-state)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> However, I'm confused that why they're in different positions?

```
{isPlayerA &&
  <Counter person="Taylor" />
}
{!isPlayerA &&
  <Counter person="Sarah" />
}
```

I think the main thing you're missing is that `false` matters when we're talking about the position of the nodes.

This code produces 2 child nodes. If isPlayerA is true, we are outputting a `<Counter>` element, followed by `false`. If isPlayerA is false, the two children are now `false` followed by a `<Counter>` element.

So since the first child has changed types (Counter -> false), it gets unmounted. And since the second child has changed types (false -> Counter), it mounts.

> and why another conditional rendering pattern(see the comment above) can preserve state?

```
{isPlayerA ? <Counter person="Taylor" /> : <Counter person="Sarah" />}
```

This code produces 1 child node.  If isPlayerA is true, we output a `<Counter>`. If isPlayerA is false, we *also* output a `<Counter>`. Since the type hasn't changed, no unmounting/remounting occurs, and react just updates the props of the existing instance.

> In the above experiment, the Counter state is preserved also. However, Counter component will be in different position when the isPlayer state changed.

```
{isPlayerA && <div>Up</div>}
{isPlayerA ? <Counter  person="Taylor" /> : <Counter  person="Sarah" />} 
{!isPlayerA && <div>Down</div>}
```

In this code you have 3 nodes. The first is either false, or a div. The second is always a Counter. The third is either false or a div. Since the second one is always a Counter, it will never remount.

Answer (score 0):

Hello from the subtitle itselfs describe the solution **[Option 1: Rendering a component in different positions](https://react.dev/learn/preserving-and-resetting-state#option-1-rendering-a-component-in-different-positions)**

This means that the `Counter` component was rendered in two different position

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35499998)