# How are the following two statements different in React?

Tags: reactjs

I was looking at the react docs today (https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/preserving-and-resetting-state), and I'm a bit confused on something.

In the docs, it says that you can force the state to reset by rendering a component in different positions, I get that.

When `isPlayerA` state changes, this one does not reset the state for `Counter`:

```
// App.js

import { useState } from 'react';

export default function Scoreboard() {
  const [isPlayerA, setIsPlayerA] = useState(true);
  return (
    <div>
      {isPlayerA ? (
        <Counter person="Taylor" />
      ) : (
        <Counter person="Sarah" />
      )}
      <button onClick={() => {
        setIsPlayerA(!isPlayerA);
      }}>
        Next player!
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

function Counter({ person }) {
  const [score, setScore] = useState(0);
  const [hover, setHover] = useState(false);

  let className = 'counter';
  if (hover) {
    className += ' hover';
  }

  return (
    <div
      className={className}
      onPointerEnter={() => setHover(true)}
      onPointerLeave={() => setHover(false)}
    >
      <h1>{person}'s score: {score}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => setScore(score + 1)}>
        Add one
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When `isPlayerA` state changes, this one **DOES** reset the state for `Counter`:

```
return (
    <div>
      {isPlayerA &&
        <Counter person="Taylor" />
      }
      {!isPlayerA &&
        <Counter person="Sarah" />
      }
      <button onClick={() => {
        setIsPlayerA(!isPlayerA);
      }}>
        Next player!
      </button>
    </div>
  );
```

In both situations, it seems to be that `Counter` is getting rendered in the same position, so why is the second one resetting the state? Are there two `Counter` components in the UI tree on the second one where state does get reset?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React resetting and preserving state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70253988/react-resetting-and-preserving-state)