# Question about preserving and resetting state in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, frontend, web-frontend

Why do these 2 code examples result in different behaviors?

using ternary: https://react.dev/learn/preserving-and-resetting-state#resetting-state-at-the-same-position

using conditional AND: https://react.dev/learn/preserving-and-resetting-state#option-1-rendering-a-component-in-different-positions

My guess is that using conditional AND that way adds a stray {false} somewhere, changing the order of the elements and causing react to notice a difference and reset the state accordingly. But then why does this code reset the state when going one way but not the other?

```
{isPlayerA ? (
  <>
    {false}<Counter person="Taylor" />
  </>
) : (
  <>
    <Counter person="Sarah" />
  </>
)}
```

Edit: Putting a space between `{false}` and `<Counter` like so `{false} <Counter` now always resets the score state correctly, but why?

Comment: Why you have to guess something when there is already explanation there in the documentation. In the ternary example you don't change the order, It was ```Counter``` and it is ```Counter``` again (with Fragment), it always return the same thing. With AND you change order, sometimes it is boolean (false) and sometimes it is ```Counter```

Comment: @OktayYuzcan I actually do have to do a lot of guess work because of how unclear and handwavy this section is. On that page it states _"it’s the position in the UI tree—not in the JSX markup—that matters"_, so why should anyone assume that a boolean, which does not even get shown in the DOM, should make any difference? The doc completely glosses over _why_ we now magically have 2 different positions. If you were correct, the code snippet in my post should always reset the state, which it doesn't. (funnily it does when you add a space inbetween `{false}` and `<Counter`, mind explaining that?)

Comment: In your example if the condition is true, it compiles into something like that ```React.createElement(React.Fragment, null, [false, React.createElement(Counter, {person: 'Taylor'})])``` and if false - into the same thing, without the false in the children. On each render it compares them. the first index in old children was ```Counter```, in new one is false, so it unmounts ```Counter```, and returns false. Then checks the next index. It was undefined, now it is Counter, so it mounts Counter. This is why the state gets lost. 2 Counters are not in same place in the Virtual DOM

Comment: ```[false, React.createElement(Counter, {person: 'Taylor'})]``` and ```[React.createElement(Counter, {person: 'Sarah'})]``` those are the children of the Fragment between the renders. Depending of the condition only one of them is returned. They are compared by their index of the array.

Comment: @OktayYuzcan I already figured as much but you keep ignoring all other points I brought up.

Comment: Its not about what is shown in the DOM, but what is stored in the Virtual DOM. Those positions are not magically. Boolean, null, empty string... they are not shown in the DOM, that is true, but they all are ReactNode. Each node matters, and their positions as well. You can create a component that accepts children and returns it and if you log the children prop, you will see that it converts into array if multiple nodes are passed, regardless if they are boolean, null, empty string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React resetting and preserving state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70253988/react-resetting-and-preserving-state)

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, React renders them inside the same block *{ }* - pay attention to this. In a sense, these components can be called one whole because either 1 or 2 will be rendered, but always in one block.

In the second case, each of the components is rendered inside its own *{ }* block, so they are independent of each other and therefore their state is not saved

Comment: You say in the second case both components get rendered which is confusing to me since in regular javascript the evaluation would stop at a falsy value before a `&&` and the rest would simply be ignored, example: `0 && console.log("foo");` the function would not get called here whatsoever. To me the code looks like in the end there should always only be 1 `<Counter/>` component left to render at the same exact position in the DOM whether `isPlayerA` is true or false, preventing the counter state from being reset.