# How is the component position inside its parent calculated?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I was going through the React docs and I encountered one example that I don't quite understand.

In that example, they explain that when you have identical components in different `positions` inside their parent, then the state of the components gets reset.

https://react.dev/learn/preserving-and-resetting-state#option-1-rendering-a-component-in-different-positions

#### Rendering a component in different positions

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function Scoreboard() {
  const [isPlayerA, setIsPlayerA] = useState(true);
  return (
    <div>
      {isPlayerA &&
        <Counter person="Taylor" />
      }
      {!isPlayerA &&
        <Counter person="Sarah" />
      }
      <button onClick={() => {
        setIsPlayerA(!isPlayerA);
      }}>
        Next player!
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

function Counter({ person }) {
  const [score, setScore] = useState(0);
  const [hover, setHover] = useState(false);

  let className = 'counter';
  if (hover) {
    className += ' hover';
  }

  return (
    <div
      className={className}
      onPointerEnter={() => setHover(true)}
      onPointerLeave={() => setHover(false)}
    >
      <h1>{person}'s score: {score}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => setScore(score + 1)}>
        Add one
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

> Initially, isPlayerA is true. So the first position contains Counter state, and the second one is empty.

> When you click the “Next player” button the first position clears but the second one now contains a Counter.

I don't understand this example and how it works. For me, both `Counter` components are in the same position: 1st (and only) child of the `div`. Why do they say, `Counters` are in different positions?

Comment: switching players causes the associated `Counter` component to be unmounted, since state is held at the `Counter` level, when it is next switched it will be remounted and the state will be reinitialized, thus losing the previous score. This not only illustrates an element of the component lifecycle but also the importance of lifting state up.

Comment: @pilchard does it get unmounted in this example? https://react.dev/learn/preserving-and-resetting-state#same-component-at-the-same-position-preserves-state
Because it keeps the state after being replaced with another component of the same type at the same position. I don't see how these examples are different...

Comment: It is poorly explained. It isn't about the position in the JSX *or* in the DOM as rendered, but in React's [render tree](https://react.dev/learn/understanding-your-ui-as-a-tree#the-render-tree). The ternary means that a only a single component can ever be rendered in that 'position' ({`true ? 'true' : 'false':`}),  where as with two unrelated conditions both *could* be rendered at the same time (`{true && 'true'} {true && 'true'}`).

Comment: @pilchard I think I'm starting to grasp it... After reading the article I was sure they were talking about the position inside the resulting JSX/DOM... Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React resetting and preserving state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70253988/react-resetting-and-preserving-state)